# JQuery - Custom function works once, then not recognized

Tags: jquery, function

So I got this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.loadView = function(a){
    };

    $('#id').click(function(){
        $.fn.loadView();
    });

    $.fn.loadView();
});
```

So when the code loads up the initialized `$.fn.loadView()` just fine the first time. But then when `$('#id').click` is activated I get this error

```
$.fn.loadView is not a function
```

Whats really making me mad is that I just got done doing something exactly like this on another project and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're not including jQuery twice in the page, this is the most common cause of plugin functions being undefined later.  Since a later include replaces the `jQuery`/`$` object, all methods defined on it are lost.

Comment: LOL i would have never suspected this... least now its out here on the internet. I was searching all over for a possible answer. Thank you :)

Comment: oh, by the way, have a nice wedding! ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nFDfC/), this works.
Maybe you're include jquery twice, as @nick said.